# javascript arrow function with ()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I know arrow function will return for me if return keyword is not found in the function body. But I saw this

```
export default handleActions({
  [SET_LOADING]: (state, { payload }) => ({
    ...state, loading: payload
  })
})
```

What is ({}) here? {} is an object, how can I see what is in the payload or state? I did this

```
export default handleActions({
  [SET_LOADING]: (state, { payload }) => {
     console.log(state) //not called
    return {...state, loading: payload}
  })
}
```

Is both of them identical?

Comment: yes both of them are identical.

Comment: if `console.log(state)` is *not called*, that means the function `(state, { payload }) => {` isn't being called at all

Comment: Anyway I think you have messed up between `Action` and `Reducer`. The code above that you've shared looks more like a reducer to me instead of an action

Comment: "What is ({})" - in arrow, you can't `() => {x:1, y:2}` you have to wrap a returned object in `()` ... this is [documented here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: @JaromandaX it's a valid redux-action syntax, the console wasn't been log but the function is called, I can guarantee that.

Comment: that's completely and utterly impossible - unless `state` is `undefined` ... then perhaps the console.log would not output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use an arrow function to return an object literal, you have to wrap the body in `()`

I.e.

```
const first = (x, y) => x * y // Standard stuff
const second = (x, y) => {foo: x, bar: y} // Wrong!
const second = (x, y) => ({foo: x, bar: y}) // Correct, returning an object literal
```

---

See the [Advanced syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) documentation section.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function f({ name }){
 console.log(name);
}

let human = {name: 'a', age: 27}
f(human)
```

Simple demonstration as above. We will define a parameter for function f as above that accepts a single parameter, object, that has a property of name. But for this method, we only care about name and not age. So we can use object destructuring to just focus on one particular property

And below is the way without destructuring, for your better understanding

```js
function f(humanParam){
     console.log(humanParam.name);
    }

    let human = {name: 'a', age: 27}
    f(human)
```